# Include yaml object as child object with Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

Let's say I have a playbook that uses two roles like this.

```yaml
---
- hosts: database
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: foo_role_one
    - role: foo_role_two
```

And I have a file in `/group_vars/database/vars.yml` like this.

```yaml
---
username: bar
```

The username variable is used by both `foo_role_one` and `foo_role_two`, but the values are not identical. I know I could include the variable directly as a child of `- role: foo_role_one`, but I am attempting to keep my playbooks clean with the variables for groups and and hosts in their own files. To accomplish this I'd like to do some like this.

```yaml
---
- hosts: database
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: foo_role_one
      '{{ foo_one }}'
    - role: foo_role_two
      '{{ foo_two }}'
```

And then in `/group_vars/database/vars.yml` have the following.

```yaml
---
foo_one:
  username: bar
foo_two:
  username: baz
```

I cannot find a syntax with the yaml spec that will allow me to do this. I thought anchors and references would do it, but it appears that they do not span yaml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find what you're looking for right in the [roles documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level), which shows, for example in which two roles both want variables named `dir` and `app_port`, but the values for each role need to be different:

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - common
    - role: foo_app_instance
      vars:
        dir: '/opt/a'
        app_port: 5000
      tags: typeA
    - role: foo_app_instance
      vars:
        dir: '/opt/b'
        app_port: 5001
      tags: typeB
```

I believe that's the same situation you're asking about.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a solution like this, but I think you are right. This is probably the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: I understand now what you're trying to do. I think you'll find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477012/how-to-use-a-dictionary-of-registered-ansible-variables-in-vars) to be of interest (but not of help).